# NginX Server block on GitLab is ignored

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I've installed GitLab on a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure in which I also have an Apache2 web server that should respond with some static websites.

Since GitLab has an embedded NGinX web server I thought that it would have been sufficient to just make these two changes:

- Make apache listen to another port rather than 80 (I changed it to 8090)
- Add a server block to GitLab's NGinX (firstly by adding this configuration to gitlab.rb `nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"` and then by creating the following block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/serverblock.conf)

  server {
        root /var/www/;
        server_name .notgitlabdomain.com;

  ```
    access_log /etc/nginx/logs/notgitlabdomain_access.log;
    error_log /etc/nginx/logs/notgitlabdomain_error.log;

    location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8090;
          add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
          add_header NLC_S "s";
    }
  ```

  }

The problem is that this is not working so far. I opened and checked whether the nginx.conf (in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/) file is actually reading the server block I added and it is. But when I follow a link in my notgitlabdomain.com domain it redirects me to notgitlabdomain.com/users/sign_in with a Sass error that couldn't import a some css files.

Answer (score 0):

Open develop tools and check the request.

I guess this issue is related about the configuration of gitlab (domain url)